# The button was not displayed after intsallation, why this happens?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a simple login app by using phone number authentication, 
the application was successfully installed but there is no button field, 
I'm already declared in XML code, the phone number field is there, but the button filed was not seen.

what kind of problem is this and how can I solve it?

Here is the button field XML:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btSend"
   android:layout_width="355dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="344dp"
   android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="339dp"
   android:text="send OTP" />
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context="com.example.krushi.TuserActivity">
   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/tphone"
      android:layout_width="385dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="241dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
      android:hint="Enter phone number here"
      android:inputType="phone" />
   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btSend"
      android:layout_width="355dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="344dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="339dp"
      android:text="send OTP" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**main:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TuserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText tphnumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuser);

      tphnumber = findViewById(R.id.tphone);
      Button btSend = findViewById(R.id.btSend);
      btSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              String mobile = tphnumber.getText().toString().trim();
                   if(mobile.isEmpty() || mobile.length() < 10){
                        tphnumber.setError("Enter a valid mobile");
                        tphnumber.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }

          Intent intent = new Intent(TuserActivity.this, VerifyPhoneActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("mobile", mobile);
                 startActivity(intent);
          }
       });
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you having that many `layout_margin` in view ? Why not Just Use `LinearLayout` as a root..

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your **XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.krushi.TuserActivity">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tphone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="Enter phone number here"
        android:inputType="phone" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btSend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tphone"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="send OTP" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @AbhijithPoojary I'm very glad to help you. If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have just edited your xml and it works very well. Here is your concise and sophisticated solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tphone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint="Enter phone number here"
        android:inputType="phone" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btSend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="send OTP" />
</LinearLayout>
```